# Should I create a new git feature branch when I'm developing a project from scratch?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

I'm using git by following the github flow document [here](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/).

The document says that you should create a new branch when you're developing a new feature.

But what if I'm developing a project from scratch?

I mean the project now only has a master branch which contains `README.md`, `package.json`, and other basic folders and files. The master branch is not deployable yet.

Should I still create a new branch when developing a new feature at this early stage?

One of the drawbacks of creating a new branch at this time is that `feature1` branch may have conflicts with `feature2` branch, which is later developed. And `feature2` branch becomes highly dependent on `feature1` branch.

I created an undeployable master branch because I write the code on different computers. Having the code stored on github makes it easy to synchronize the code between the two computers.

Comment: I would personally build a minimal framework of files, make an initial commit to `master` as the very first starting point, and then branch from there.  Not sure what git flow would have to say about this.

Comment: I created an undeployable master branch because I write the code on different computers. Having the code stored on github makes it easy to synchronize the code between the two computers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner, understand that your master is a non-conflicting, clean and deployable version of the code is stored.

For the developing of new features, it is better to create a new branch, let's name it as "dev" branch, and make a clone or switch to the dev branch using the following command:

```
 git checkout -b dev
```

Now, if you want to develop a feature then create a new branch on dev and start working.

Once the work is completed, create a "pull request" and then merge the branch to the dev branch once it is approved.

Similarly, the case of rebasing goes for the master branch from dev

Answer (score 0):

Whether create a feature branch from undeployable `master` branch is depend on how you develop the project.

- If **you are the only developer for the project**, it's unnecessary to create feature branch here since you are the only one developer.
- If **there are multiple developers work on the project**, you should create new feature branch and work on the feature branch instead.

  And don't worry about `feature2` depend on `feature1` since **feature branches are short-living branches**. That means when you finish the work on `feature1` branch, you should merge the changes from `feature1` into `master` branch.

  Even if there are multiple feature branches (such as `feature2` and `feature3` etc) not merge into `master` branch, while `feature1` has already merged into `master` branch. Assume the commit history as below:

  ```
          C---D    feature1
         /     \
  ...---A---B---G   master
             \
              E---F  feature 2
  ```

  So When you merge `feature2` branch into `master` branch, there already has new changes deployed on `master` branch (as the merged commit `G` in graph). And you can rebase `feature2` branch on the top on `master` branch firstly (apply the changes from `feature1` branch into `feature2` branch), and then merge `feature2` into `master`. Detail steps as below:

  #### a. rebase feature2 on the top of master branch

  Use the commands:

  ```
  git checkout feature2
  git pull origin master
  ```

  Then the commit history will be:

  ```
          C---D    feature1
         /     \
  ...---A---B---G   master
                 \
                  E'---F'  feature 2
  ```

  #### b. merge feature2 into master branch by:

  ```
  git checkout master
  git merge feature2
  ```

  And the commit history will be:

  ```
          C---D    feature1
         /     \
  ...---A---B---G---E'---F'   master, feature2
  ```

  Then you can merge other existing feature branches (`feature3` etc) into `master` branch by the same way.